# How to bind a Timeline chart with a ControlWrapper in order to filter the Timeline

Tags: javascript, html, charts, google-visualization

I'm trying to filter the chart (timeline) based on the value in the chartwrapper (listbox).

The documentation states that you need to declare both the controlWrapper and the chartWrapper. 
I'm declaring the timeline a bit different and I'm assuming that's why both elements can't interact correctly.

```
 var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
 var compPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
            'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
            'containerId': 'control2',
            dataTable: data,
            'options': {
              'filterColumnLabel': 'Team',
              'ui': {
              'labelStacking': 'vertical',
                'allowTyping': true,
                'allowMultiple': true
              }
            }
          });
dashboard.bind(compPicker, chart);
compPicker.draw();
              // Draw the entire dashboard.

google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', afterDraw);
chart.draw(data, options);
```

I can successfully present the control values but when I pick one the timeline doesn't filter.

Here's a codepen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XQdYrm

Update: Codepen updated to reflect the correct result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, add the `'controls'` package to the same `load` statement as `'timeline'`.

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['controls', 'timeline']
}).then(function () {
```

next, need to use a `ChartWrapper` object for the Timeline chart.

```
var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
  chartType: 'Timeline',
  containerId: 'chart'
});
```

finally, need to draw the dashboard, instead of the control and chart separately.

```
dashboard.bind(compPicker, chart);
dashboard.draw(data);
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['controls', 'timeline']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable({
    cols: [
      {id: 'team', label: 'Team', type: 'string'},
      {id: 'start', label: 'Season Start Date', type: 'date'},
      {id: 'end', label: 'Season End Date', type: 'date'}
    ],
    rows: [
      {c: [{v: 'Baltimore Ravens'},     {v: 'Date(2000, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2001, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'New England Patriots'}, {v: 'Date(2001, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2002, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'Tampa Bay Buccaneers'}, {v: 'Date(2002, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2003, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'New England Patriots'}, {v: 'Date(2003, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2004, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'New England Patriots'}, {v: 'Date(2004, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2005, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'Pittsburgh Steelers'},  {v: 'Date(2005, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2006, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'Indianapolis Colts'},   {v: 'Date(2006, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2007, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'New York Giants'},      {v: 'Date(2007, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2008, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'Pittsburgh Steelers'},  {v: 'Date(2008, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2009, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'New Orleans Saints'},   {v: 'Date(2009, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2010, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'Green Bay Packers'},    {v: 'Date(2010, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2011, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'Green Bay Packers'},    {v: 'Date(2010, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2011, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'New England Patriots'}, {v: 'Date(2001, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2002, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'Tampa Bay Buccaneers'}, {v: 'Date(2002, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2003, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'New England Patriots'}, {v: 'Date(2003, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2004, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'New England Patriots'}, {v: 'Date(2004, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2005, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'Pittsburgh Steelers'},  {v: 'Date(2005, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2006, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'New York Giants'},      {v: 'Date(2007, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2008, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'Pittsburgh Steelers3'},  {v: 'Date(2008, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2009, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'New Orleans Saints2'},   {v: 'Date(2009, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2010, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'Green Bay Packers'},    {v: 'Date(2010, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2011, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'Green Bay Packers4'},    {v: 'Date(2010, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2011, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'New England Patriots5'}, {v: 'Date(2001, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2002, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'Tampa Bay Buccaneers6'}, {v: 'Date(2002, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2003, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'New England Patriots7'}, {v: 'Date(2003, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2004, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'New England Patriots8'}, {v: 'Date(2004, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2005, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'Pittsburgh Steelers9'},  {v: 'Date(2005, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2006, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'New York Giants10'},      {v: 'Date(2007, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2008, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'Pittsburgh Steelers11'},  {v: 'Date(2008, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2009, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'New Orleans Saints12'},   {v: 'Date(2009, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2010, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'Green Bay Packers13'},    {v: 'Date(2010, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2011, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'Green Bay Packers14'},    {v: 'Date(2010, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2011, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'New England Patriots15'}, {v: 'Date(2001, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2002, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'Tampa Bay Buccaneers16'}, {v: 'Date(2002, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2003, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'New England Patriots17'}, {v: 'Date(2003, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2004, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'New England Patriots18'}, {v: 'Date(2004, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2005, 1, 5)'}]},
      {c: [{v: 'Pittsburgh Steelers19'},  {v: 'Date(2005, 8, 5)'}, {v: 'Date(2006, 1, 5)'}]},
    ]
  });

  var options = {
    height: 1300,
    timeline: {
      groupByRowLabel: true
    },
    width: 1800
  };
  var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard'));
  var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'Timeline',
    containerId: 'chart'
  });

  var compPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
    containerId: 'control2',
    options: {
      filterColumnLabel: 'Team',
      ui: {
        labelStacking: 'vertical',
        allowTyping: true,
        allowMultiple: true
      }
    }
  });

  dashboard.bind(compPicker, chart);
  dashboard.draw(data);
});
```

```css
#header {
  height: 0px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  display: block;
  top: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  z-index: 99;
    float: top;
}

#chart {
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  margin-top: 57px;
  
}

.scroll {
  max-width: 100%;
   -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
   height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.inline {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
 -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  
}

.nowrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="dashboard">
  <div id="control2"></div>
  <div class="nowrap">
    <div class="inline" id="labels"></div>
    <div class="inline scroll">
      <div id="header"></div>
      <div id="chart"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, it can. I just had to set the options inside the chartwrapper and move all the variables on top of the method declaration. Thank you!